# json_decode is not working in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have this `json_encode` data:

```
{\"MOT:D44-538JK\":{\"productid\":\"MOT:D44-538JK\",\"qty\":\"1\"}}
```

When I use `json_decode` on the above string it is not working. Any one can assist what parameters need to pass to work.

Comment: Remove the backslashes.

Comment: The above string is from json_encode.

Comment: Your reduced test case is too reduced. You appear to have missed out the string delimiters, and the call to `json_decode`. http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1):

Your data is encoded already.

```
php > var_dump(json_decode("{\"MOT:D44-538JK\":{\"productid\":\"MOT:D44-538JK\",\"qty\":\"1\"}}", true));
array(1) {
  'MOT:D44-538JK' =>
  array(2) {
    'productid' =>
    string(13) "MOT:D44-538JK"
    'qty' =>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

Comment: when I am doing this json_decode("{\"MOT:D44-538JK\":{\"productid\":\"MOT:D44-538JK\",\"qty\":\"1\"}}", true));
not giving the array.

Comment: That's why I called `json_decode('str', true)` - 2nd parameter = return data as array, not as object.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON does not validate. Test it here: http://jsonlint.com
This does, so the slashes need to go.

```
{
    "MOT:D44-538JK": {
        "productid": "MOT: D44-538JK",
        "qty": "1"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove "\" from jsonstring

```
<?php 
    $c = '{"MOT:D44-538JK":{"productid":"MOT:D44-538JK","qty":"1"}}';
    $r = json_decode($c);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($r);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your JSON has padding. Please remove the padding then process further:

```
$json=preg_replace('/.+?({.+}).+/','$1',$json); 

// now, process the JSON string 

$result = json_decode($body);
```

Answer (score 0):

> try this

```
$Json = '{"MOT:D44-538JK":{"productid":"MOT:D44-538JK","qty":"1"}}';
$jsonDec = json_decode($Json, true);
var_dump($jsonDec);
```

> OUTPUT Like this:

```
array (size=1)
'MOT:D44-538JK' => 
array (size=2)
  'productid' => string 'MOT:D44-538JK' (length=13)
  'qty' => string '1' (length=1)
```